# best way to approach a coverage analysis

Tags: python

I have a script that places an object and moves a camera around this object following a predetermined trajectory.

What would be the best way to compute what percentage of the overall object's surface is being observed throughout the trajectory? Since there is a light source, seeing a part of the object would require some light being reflected off the object and into the camera - if I point the camera at a dark part of the object this should not count as "seen" surface.

I'm primarily wondering if there is an easy (script-based) way of approaching this.

Thanks!